# Isn't polymorphism just a effect of encapsulation?

Tags: java

I have been reading Herbert Schildt's Java "The Complete reference"8th edition.

There's this paragraph in it,on page 22 of chapter 2.

> The final attribute, polymorphism, is clearly reflected in the ability
>   of car manufacturers  to offer a wide array of options on basically
>   the same vehicle. For example, you can get an  antilock braking system
>   or traditional brakes, power or rack-and-pinion steering, and 4-, 6-, 
>   or 8-cylinder engines. Either way, you will still press the brake
>   pedal to stop, turn the steering  wheel to change direction, and press
>   the accelerator when you want to move. The same  interface can be used
>   to control a number of different implementations

Now,In the same chapter on encapsulation page 18,

> Further, what occurs inside the transmission does not affect objects
>   outside the transmission. For example, shifting gears  does not turn
>   on the headlights! Because an automatic transmission is encapsulated,
>   dozens  of car manufacturers can implement one in any way they please.
>   However, from the driver’s  point of view, they all work the same.
>   This same idea can be applied to programming.
>
> Isn't the only reason that car manufacturer can vary these ( antilock
>   braking system or traditional brakes, power or rack-and-pinion
>   steering, and 4-, 6-,  or 8-cylinder engines) because the rest of the
>   systems are encapsulated from these and won't be affected by changing
>   them?

I'm sorry, if I'm going wrong somewhere.

My question is,

Does encapsulation really have a cause and effect relationship with polymorphism?

Comment: in practice both ideas (agree) have common point, can be symbolically described "good OOP practice". But are different in theory: possible is polymorphism without encapsulation (all members public) and vice versa (encapsulation without class inheritance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With encapsulation your car is made out of various parts.  You might have 4x wheels, headlights, etc. and they are all contained in "Car".  a Car doesn't have to know how to Light Up, it just asks the headlights to do that via a switch.

With Polymorphism you can replace one system (Implementation) with a different one and not notice.  For instance, you could possibly replace your headlights with LED headlights.  They are a completely different system but you still just hit the same switch and they come on.

So I guess you could say that the lights being contained in the car is Encapsulation, being able to switch them to a different implementation without changing the interface you are using is polymorphism.

Also, just as a generality, Encapsulation often uses the same code--You don't typically switch how your encapsulated classes are implemented at runtime EXCEPT when you also combine polymorphism--polymorphism is how your encapsulated class might change code/implementation as well as data at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

They're two distinct concepts. Either could exist without the other.

Encapsulation refers to a class or module not exposing it's internal implementation details. It's a black box. You observe the inputs and outputs. How it gets from the input *to* the output should be hidden and protected from potential external interference.

Polymorphism, or more specifically subtyping, is a way to share common implementation details: fields, methods, etc. So in way you could argue this "sharing" actually breaks encapsulation somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, polymorphism is not encapsulation.

Polymorphism is the name given to an "is-a" relationship between a parent and a child class.

Encapsulation is the name given to a "has-a" relationship between two classes.

Example from the real world:
*Polymorphism:* A Lexus is a car.
*Encapsulation:* A Lexus has an engine.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation and polymorphism both have the idea of "implementation", but the two have different perspectives.

To expand on your book's car example the two perspectives can be show as follows. Let's assume you have an interface that defines the following method:

```
interface Vehicle {
    public void start();
}
```

**About polymorphism:**

Polymorphism is about the ability to view and use the **type** in a uniform way, while it can concretely be of various **types**:

```
Vehicle vehicle;

vehicle = new AutomaticCar();
vehicle.start(); //runs automatic car's logic

vehicle = new ManualCar();
vehicle.start(); //runs manual car's logic
```

The variable `vehicle` is declared and used in a uniform way, but it can be of **different forms**, meaning it can be concretely represented by different types. Further to this, when `vehicle.start()` runs, it's the `run` implementation provided by the actual class. This means that the first `vehicle.start()` is going to execute according to an automatic car's details, whereas the second one will execute according to a manual car's details. In this, it's polymorphic. Remember: polymorphism looks at **types** and behavior specific to types.

**About Encapsulation:**

Encapsulation looks at a class from the perspective of its implementation details **with regard to other classes**. To illustrate, let's pseudo-code the two classes:

```
class AutomaticCar implements Vehicle {
    public void start() {
        this.doAutomaticMagic();
    }

    private void doAutomaticMagic() {
        //clever automatic stuff
    }
}
```

Let's suppose this class had a direct client:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        AutomaticCar automaticCar = new AutomaticCar();
        automaticCar.doAutomaticMagic(); //PROBLEM HERE
    }
}
```

Now, we all know that `automaticCar.doAutomaticMagic();` in `Main` will not be allowed to compile, but let's see the theory: the class `AutomaticCar` has encapsulated the implementation details of its `start` method, meaning that it has prevented other classes from directly interacting with its specific logic. This could be said about data as well.

Unlike polymorphism which is about types providing implementations for interfaces, encapsulation is about implementation details and/or data being inaccessible to **other classes**. Polymorphism is about types, but encapsulation is about what classes hold and do (of course, these concepts can be extended, such as to packages and modules). But both of these aspects can be looked at as "implementation" details (at least in a way)

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation and polymorphism are two concepts that are different from each other.

[Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) comes from the idea of encapsulating or putting a wall or membrane around something to isolate and protect what is inside from what is outside.

[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) comes from the idea of having a single interface but several different versions of the functionality, from the Greek poly or many and morphism or form.

With polymorphic interfaces the data type of the arguments is known and the compiler determines which of the various possible polymorphic functions or methods it is to use based on the data type of the arguments. If there is no function or method with the specified data types provided then if you try to use the polymorphic interface with those data types, you will see an error.

[Generics in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html) as well as templates in C++ provide a way to have a more flexible approach to polymorphism by allowing a class to be described as a kind of general class description or template which the programmer can use by specifying the particular data type to be used by the compiler to generate a specific class. However if the generic uses an interface of some other class that is not supported by the specified data type being used to instantiate the generic, then the compiler will issue an error.

Typically polymorphic interfaces use encapsulation in order to provide a known contract with the programmer. As part of designing a family of polymorphic functions or methods or classes, the programmer does their best to encapsulate the logic and data so as to reduce the dependencies on functions that could break the polymorphism.

However using encapsulation with polymorphic code is just using sound software engineering and you are perfectly able to write source code that breaks encapsulation with polymorphic functions, methods, and classes.

You can have encapsulation without polymorphism and encapsulation can be expressed in other than object oriented programming languages. For instance in the C programming language it is possible to have encapsulated functionality and C doesn't have the concept of polymorphism though it is possible to approximate polymorphism with some work arounds.

**An Example of Encapsulation without Polymorphism**

In the C Standard Library there is the `bsearch()` function that will search a sorted array for a matching item. The designers of the function did not have polymorphism as a built in attribute of the C programming language yet they wanted to encapsulate the search behavior and provide an interface that would be useful for a wide range of data types and data structures so they did the following.

First of all they wanted the `bsearch()` function to accept any data type for the array items to search as well as the item to be searched for. So they used `void` pointers for these arguments along with requiring the user to specify the size of each item as well as the number of items in the array.

But then they were faced with the comparison that needed to be done and how could the `bsearch()` function compare any kind of data as a part of doing its search. So the designers used a [dependency injection approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and added to the interface of the `bsearch()` function a requirement that the user must provide a comparison function that will return one of three values (-1, 0, 1) depending on the collating sequence of the two items being compared.

So the `bsearch()` function ended up with the following interface:

```
void *bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
```

A programmer can use the `bsearch()` function to do the search of an array of sorted values of any data type. The comparison logic is encapsulated in the `compar()` function which the `bsearch()` function calls during the search when it wants to compare data values. The `bsearch()` function uses some kind of a search, which is also encapsulated, and as long as the data provided is sorted and the `compar()` function provides the required output, the search algorithm, normally a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), works.

While this idea of searching an array of any data type may sound like polymorphism, it is not. The `bsearch()` function uses `void` pointers so that it doesn't need to know anything about the data type of the array or the item being searched. Instead the function takes a couple of pointers and is doing pointer or address arithmetic to process the array elements.